# Creating html table within a table using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, html-table

Trying to figure out what im doing wrong. What im doing is creating a table within a table. Note the function below that make the table works, tested it. Here is my code below, any help would be appreciated. What its showing when i run it, is the last row in the control(table) that im creating.

```
 Dim tblrow As TableRow
 Dim tblcell As TableCell

 tblrow = New TableHeaderRow

 tblcell = New TableHeaderCell
 tblcell.Controls.Add(add_table(zone_name, hgt, randomNum, fontSize, tblID))
 tblrow.Cells.Add(tblcell)

  Table1.Rows.Add(tblrow)
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more details about your requirement. Its not clear. try to provide your HTML markup and complete codes from the code behind file.

Comment: You indicate that you're seeing the last row in the control(table), but you don't indicate any looping operation in this code. Try supplying more code as the underlying issue is likely elsewhere in your code.